# Cannot close all Google Chrome processes on Windows 10 and cannot run the browser

Tags: google-chrome, uninstallation

My symptoms are as follows:

**1.** Cannot run Google Chrome; Task Manager tells me there are a single chrome.exe sitting in RAM, and the Task Manager cannot kill it:

[image: Cannot kill chrome.exe]

**2.** Since the process is still in RAM, I cannot reinstall the Google Chrome:

[image: Cannot install Google Chrome]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the command prompt to terminate the process:

1. Search for cmd/Command Prompt in the search bar.
2. Open cmd with "Run as Administrator." option (Use right-click to get the menu).
3. Use the command tasklist to list all processes.
4. Use the command taskkill /F /IM "chrome.exe" /T to terminate all its processes.

Comment: this is the best version of the answer.

Comment: Works with selenium chromedriver.exe/geckodriver.exe as well

Answer (score 2):

Restarting your computer would take care of the RAM issue.. from there, you should be able to uninstall chrome no problem. As for not being able to kill the chrome processes in task manager, that seems like a permissions thing.

Additionally, it might be beneficial for you to disable all chrome plugins and extensions, and check again if you can kill any chrome tasks with task manager. If that doesn't solve it, try to clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer to fix the RAM issue, then try to reinstall chrome, if there is some process running on it then run task manager as administrator and then kill those processes.

Answer (score 1):

@Aayush Sethi answer should solve your problem.

For completion, I might add my personal app that I wrote based on the same concept Aayush wrote.

Source: https://github.com/AndreiLucaci/killapp

Binary: https://github.com/AndreiLucaci/killapp/releases/download/v1.0.0/KillApp.exe

Answer (score 1):

For me, **Aayush Sethin’s solution** is the best. When I close the Chrome browser (v.107.0.5304.88 x64), the task is still processing. If I want to open a new browser window again I must go to Task Manager and kill the Chrome task. I have created a *«bat file»* with the command line, `taskkill /F /IM "chrome.exe" /T`,  so as not to have to enter the Task Manager.

Comment: This worked for me. If you get the "access denied" error then you need to open the command prompt in administrator mode first.

Answer (score 0):

The TASKKILL command didn't work for me, I got the same "access denied" error posted above.  I found another solution using the System Configuration tool, which describes how to disable services from running when you reboot.  I disabled the Google services before rebooting again, and that was the only thing that worked.  I was finally able to uninstall Chrome with no errors, no phantom Google Chrome windows open.  It's detailed here:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on an old Win7 Laptop just now. TASKKILL doesn't work, even when issued from a CMD session run as Administrator.  Errors are of the form

ERROR:  The process with PID 28264 (child process of PID 28448) could not be terminated.
Reason: there is no running instance of the task.

My guess is that when I earlier killed off several chrome.exe processes (after Chrome became totally unresponsive), maybe one or more of those that I killed were the parents of these, and maybe those parents need to exist for the child to be properly terminated, e.g. because termination "has to be reported to the parent."  I've seen that concept in other OSes, though I don't entirely agree with the idea from a design standpoint.  And in any case, if the parent is gone, surely the proper way to handle that is to let the child be killed without having to report, not to REFUSE to kill the child!

So I'm guessing these processes are holding onto a communication endpoint,
such as a mailbox or pipe, trying to write a message back to their parent, and it's failing because the parent isn't there reading the other end and the I/O fails. Maybe if a tool could find the parent endpoint, grab it, and read it, these things could be killed without having to reboot the whole darn machine. That's a technique that works on some other OSes.