# Python how to kill all selenium/ chrome processes after close?

Tags: python, selenium, process

How can i kill all chromedriver processes when i close/ shutdown my PY app?

I thought about the idea of killing all chromeprocesses after shutdown with a method that executes before shutdown, but this will cause other chromes which werent affected from the PY to close too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command prompt to terminate the process:

1. Search for cmd/Command Prompt in the search bar.
2. Open cmd with "Run as Administrator." option (Use right-click to get the menu).
3. Use the command tasklist to list all processes.
4. Use the command taskkill /F /IM "chrome.exe" /T to terminate all its processes.

Credits to the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528390/3485434)